# Log of POJOs that you can read back programatically

Tags: java

I have a set of POJOs that I want to write to a file and have the ability to sequentially read back in the form of an iterator of POJOs

This seems like something a logging framework like logback would handle for me, especially the file handling part (rolling, archiving, ...), but is there a way to do the inverse to read back the POJOs, without writing the code myself?

(I'm assuming here I give the logging framework bytes and it gives me bytes back - but if it handles the serialization too - great)

Comment: A logging framework is probably not what you want. Can you describe in more detail what data this is and how/when you need to read it back? Maybe a database or a message queue or a transaction log is better suited here.

Comment: @Thilo - fair enough, I don't want an external service, I just want something that writes to disk - any suggestions welcome?

Comment: More details would help. Otherwise default go-to-solutions for in-process storage engine are SQLite or RocksDB.

Comment: A database seems heavy handed. I am literally storing a daily list of POJO objects that I want to be able to read back programtically.